# How can I retrieve a single record from the Google App Engine Datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Using Google App Engine and GQL and Python:

in my datastore I have something like the following

```
class Thing(db.Model):
   domain = db.StringProperty(required=True)
   name = db.StringProperty()
   ...more...
```

and in my handler I have

```
currentThing = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Thing WHERE domain=:1 LIMIT 1",
                                       "example.com")
```

I know this will at MOST return one Thing but I can't seem to find a way to collect that one thing in a Thing object without going through a looping process which seems a bit odd to me.

I've also tried using the `Thing.gql("WHERE domain=:1 LIMIT 1", "example.com")` syntax to no avail.  They all seem to return collections.

I'm coming from a .NET background and am new to Python and App Engine, but I'm looking for something similar to the .FirstOrDefault() functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a `.get()` onto the end of either of your queries.  From [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html#GqlQuery_getBlockquote):

> Executes the query, then returns the first result, or None if the query returned no results.
>
> get() implies a "limit" of 1, and overrides the LIMIT clause of the GQL query, if any. At most 1 result is fetched from the datastore.

See also `.fetch(limit, offset=0)`, which will allow you to retrieve *limit* results from the query.

Comment: I have started using the .fetch(1) method, however to get to the actual object returned i still need to use currentThing[0].  Does .get() require this as well?

Comment: Apparently it doesn't! This is exactly what I needed.